# WPF Databound Grid Scaling

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, grid

I want to bind data to a grid in `xaml`. This is the code I am using for binding it:

```
    <Grid  x:Name="Example" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  >
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ExampleImage}" />
    </Grid>
```

Now when I bind it using fixed width and height it will display the grid at set dimensions.

Code:

```
    private Grid _exampleImage;

    public Grid ExampleImage
    {
        get
        {
            if (SelectedSectie != null)
            {
                var convertFromString = System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#CCCCCC");
                if (convertFromString != null)
                {
                    DropShadowEffect dse = new DropShadowEffect
                    {
                        BlurRadius = 5,
                        ShadowDepth = 1,
                        Direction = 270,
                        Color =
                            (System.Windows.Media.Color)
                            convertFromString
                    };

                    _exampleImage = new Grid
                    {
                        Background =
                            new SolidColorBrush(SingleIcons.Helpers.ColorConverter.ToMediaColor(SelectedSectie.Color.ColorValue)),
                        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
                        Width = SelectedIconSize.Width,
                        Height = SelectedIconSize.Height,
                        MaxWidth = SelectedIconSize.Width,
                        MaxHeight = SelectedIconSize.Height,
                        HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                        Effect = dse,
                        RowDefinitions =
                        {
                            new RowDefinition {Height = new GridLength(46, GridUnitType.Star)},
                            new RowDefinition {Height = new GridLength(3, GridUnitType.Star)}
                        }
                    };
                }

                TextBlock afbeeldingTextBlock = new TextBlock
                {
                    Text = _selectedSectie.Sectie,
                    TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
                    TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                    Width = _exampleImage.Width,
                    FontSize = Global.Fontsize,
                    FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily(Global.Family.Name),
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                    Foreground =
                        new SolidColorBrush(
                            SingleIcons.Helpers.ColorConverter.ToMediaColor(SelectedSectie.Color.TextColorValue)),

                };

                TextOptions.SetTextFormattingMode(afbeeldingTextBlock, TextFormattingMode.Display);
                TextOptions.SetTextRenderingMode(afbeeldingTextBlock, TextRenderingMode.ClearType);

                Canvas bottomCanvas = new Canvas
                {
                    Background = (SolidColorBrush) (new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#26000000"))
                };

                Grid.SetRow(afbeeldingTextBlock, 0);
                Grid.SetRow(bottomCanvas, 1);

                _exampleImage.Children.Add(afbeeldingTextBlock);
                _exampleImage.Children.Add(bottomCanvas);

                _exampleImage.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(_exampleImage.Width,
                    _exampleImage.Height));
                _exampleImage.Arrange(
                    new Rect(new System.Windows.Size(_exampleImage.Width, _exampleImage.Height)));


                return _exampleImage;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
    }
```

Now what I would like to do is to keep the grid at set dimensions but allow the GUI to scale the grid, 
because when I make the window smaller the grid stays at these dimensions and it hurts the scaling of the application.

The reason I am using a databound grid is because I have another function which exports this grid to a `.png`.

Answer (score 0):

Putting it inside a Viewbox and setting StretchDirection to DownOnly was the result i wanted.

```
<Grid  x:Name="Example" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  >
        <Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly" >
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ExampleImage}" />
        </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```